# Microsoft workflow host in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, workflow-foundation

I intend to use Microsoft Workflow in my project and allow other system trigger it via rest api. So, can we host it via web api 2. I dont want to use WCF because it is heavy and will be replace by web api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workflow Foundation does not nativity support WebAPI like it does WCF, but the development team has indicated that it is definitely on their radar for a future release.

However, one of the best things about Workflow is you can invoke a workflow from any C# code. So you could create a WebAPI project and in the method simply hydrate the workflow arguments and call the workflow then pass the result back out.

```
 WorkflowInstance = new WorkflowInvoker(myWorkflow);
 var InputArguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 InputArguments.Add("MyArgument", myVariable);
 var resultDictionary = WorkflowInstance.Invoke(InputArguments);
 var result = (myResult)resultDictionary["MyResult"];
```

I've written a blog post with code examples of how to use Workflow with Web API.
http://code-coverage.net/using-windows-workflow-with-web-api/

Comment: What is the best way to host workflow within web api now that AppFabric support is ending? Mostly in resuming the workflow if IIS app pools are restarted or the server crashes. Do you have any resources on implementing on this or creating a custom monitoring solution? I'm just wondering what direction to take to replace app fabric. I asked a  question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907281/windows-workflow-foundation-on-premise-hosting-and-web-api  but  I am getting no response. I'm guessing no one really uses MS workflow very much.